# Input checking method in java

Tags: java, methods, input

I have an input checking function that takes input from the user. (It's supposed to be lower case letter and digit. It's for the battleship game.)  The function needs to remove spaces from input, lowercase it, and check to make sure that the first character is a letter, and the second is a digit.  Letters must be from a to g, and digits from 1 to 7. I wrote some code, but for some reason after any mistake, the programs ends. It should say an error message and wait for new input.  What did I do wrong?  Here is my code.

```
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        inputLine = inputLine.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        inputLine = inputLine.toLowerCase();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0)
            inputLine = null;
        else if (inputLine.length() > 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter column (a-g) and row (1-7)");
            inputLine = null;
        } else {
            if (Character.isLetter(inputLine.charAt(0))) {
                char i = inputLine.charAt(0);
                if (i < 'a' || i > 'g') {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a letter a to g");
                    inputLine = null;
                }
                int row = i - 'a';
                if (Character.isDigit(inputLine.charAt(1))) {
                    int k = (inputLine.charAt(1) - '0');
                    if (k < 1 || k > 7) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a digit 1 to 7");
                        inputLine = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    return inputLine;
}
```

Comment: please indent this code properly.

Comment: You say you want after an error it should wait for new input, where is the code that points to that requirement in your program? maybe a loop to return to the starting point of requesting new input.

Comment: how can i do that?   any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

The code block below is going to throw a null pointer exception. If the first char is invalid and the first `if` is executed, then inputline is set to `null`. Then in the next `if` you are calling a method on `inputline` (which is now null) and an exception is thrown. Instead of doing `inputline=null;`, change it to `return null;` and just return null right away.

```
if (i<'a' || i>'g')
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a letter a to g");
    inputLine = null;
}
int row = i -'a';
if (Character.isDigit(inputLine.charAt(1)))
```

Comment: thank you.  i tried changing "inputLine = null"  to "return null;" , but it still not working.. program just quits when i enter wrong input.. for example d23.. or f5..

Comment: What exception is it throwing?